# Why does my regular expression not find names?

Tags: python, regex

I am learning Python, and following along sentdex's videos. I just got to regular expressions, and copied the code he used. While the ages print out fine, when I try to print out the names I just get '[]' as an output.

```
import re
examplestring = ''' Jessica is 15 years old, and Daniel is 27 years    old.
Edward is 97, and his grandfather, Oscar, is 102
'''

ages = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}',examplestring)
name = re.findall(r'[A-Z], [a-z]*',examplestring)

print(ages)
print(name)
```

Comment: Did you want `re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*',examplestring)`? What is that comma supposed to be doing?

Comment: I would simply use the pattern `r'[A-Z][a-z]*'` otherwise it's looking for eg `"O, scar"`

Comment: @Navi, did it work for you ?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple scenarios can be possible to match name. In you case, if name is Oscar then your regex should look like this.
Regex: `[A-Z][a-z]+` there should be no comma and then space as it will try to find as CoryKramer mentioned.
`[A-Z]` means first letter is word and it is Capital.
`[a-z]` means from second letter onwards all letters are lowercase.

I have mentioned `+` instead of `*`. Difference between `+` and `*` is, 
`+` denotes at least one time so if you have word just O it will not match, your data should be at least two character like Os.

`*` denotes zero or more time so if you have word just O it will match, so if your name is any letter from Alphabet it will match. So if you think that your name can be only one letter use `*` else use `+`.

Example for *: https://regex101.com/r/n9HSIu/1
Example for +: https://regex101.com/r/hL4Pd8/1

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with you using comma(,) while writing the expression.

According to it, it will be looking for a Capital Letter(A-Z) followed by comma(,) and then space followed by n number of alphabets which your string doesn't satisfy.

For your desired result you need to eliminate comma(,) and use this instead:

```
name = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*',examplestring)
```

Comment: Instead of `*` it should be `+`. I have explaied in my answer.